# Installing SSL certificate on windows server 2016

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2016

I am hosting multiple websites on a single Windows server 2016 having one public IP. I want to install SSL certificate for my websites.
I need to know whether to install ssl separately for each of the websites or i have to install single ssl certificate for all websites

Comment: SSL certificates are bound to the domain name. If all of your websites are on the same domain name, then you only need one cert. Otherwise, you'll need multiple.

Comment: Have a look at https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/letsencrypt-on-windows-server/27983